# Indexed Storage in QLDB

Tags: indexed, amazon-qldb

What is the type of database used in indexed storage as QLDB supports storing structured, semi-structured, nested data and it doesn't enforce schema but it supports PartiQL(SQL compatible access)?

Comment: Are you asking how QLDB implements indexed storage?

Comment: Yes. Is it ok to tell more about indexed storage in QLDB?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there are no implementation details that can be shared at this point. Do you have a specific question or concern?

Answer (score 0):

QLDB is built on custom Amazon AWS technology, supports indices, and is designed to handle high OLTP transaction workloads while supporting PartiQL queries as you point out.